# Needed an efficient way for search for the following specfic requirement

Tags: hash, search, bloom-filter

I have to search a given file name (let say Keyword) in a directory  containing files. If there were only few keywords to be searched, I could have used regular search (like creating an array of file names  residing in the specified directory and then search each file name with the given keyword). Since I need to search very large number of keywords dynamically, its not efficient to search using regular. I had couple of ideas:

1.using hashing (but not clear how to design it)

2.Using Bloom Filters for searching (please google , if u dont know about it, its working is very interesting!):  Problem in using bloom filters is "False positives are possible, but false negatives are not". I might miss some results....

Comment: Also, the *point* of bloom filters is to have a cheap test for definite negatives; you always still have to do a search when a bloom filter is positive, and that's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before searching, create a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of all positive matches.

Creating the trie will take O(n) where n is the number of words.

To to search, try to match the word against the trie. Look-ups are done in O(m) where m is the *length* of the word to look-up.

Total runtime: O(n + nm) => O(nm) to find all the words.

Comment: It's not true that a trie is "more compact" than a list of words! Tries are rather space-inefficient; that's how you get the savings in time. If the search space is truly huge (the OP doesn't say) then you have to get clever, and use something like a PATRICIA, or else you simply won't have the RAM.

Comment: Hey Bens!!! thanks for the idea... space is no problem...only time has to be considered here...your idea seems to workout for me....Is there any java library for trie?

Comment: Hi Jonathan !!! "very large" here i refer is very large no. of file names to be searched..